# How can I check a JavaScript function is loaded or exists in page before calling it?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone can give me a JavaScript code snippet by which I can detect if a JavaScript function is loaded in my aspx web page or exists before calling it?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will check if your function is defined.

```
if (typeof functionName === 'function') {
  alert('loaded');
}
```

[See it.](http://jsbin.com/oyitu4/edit)

Comment: No need for `===`, as `typeof` will always return a string. In fact, `===` is a bit slower comparison than `==`.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel I thought `===` was usually faster as it didn't need to coerce types to see if they met the condition. Oh well, learn something new everyday. BTW, do you have further reading or benchmarks on that?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel No, `===` is *indeed* **faster** since there's *no* overhead for type conversion. Also it's just good practice to use `===`. Even a quick check on my node repl here proof's that, `==` is around 10x slower when a Number and a String are involved.

Comment: [Nick Craver](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) was kind enough to set up a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/triple-vs-double-equal-test). Looks like `===` *is* slower (marginally) on my machine running Firefox 3.6.12 on Windows 7. Would be interested to see what other people got :)

Comment: ...but `===` was faster on Firefox 3.6.12 on OS X.

Comment: If both operands are of the same type, `===` and `==` are specified to perform **exactly the same steps**. If there's a speed difference then it'll be down to some unspecified internal workings of the browser and is unlikely to be consistent across browsers. Therefore performance should not be consideration when deciding whether to use `==` or `===` in this situation. I'd personally use `==` because it's one character shorter.

Comment: @Tim Down Interesting... thanks for the comment. I like the `===` personally as it tells me that the return of the `typeof` operator will be a string. In case I forget :P

Comment: Here's another benchmark ( http://jsperf.com/triple-vs-double-equal-test-with-type-conversion ) that shows how much slower `==` is when different types are involved.

Comment: @Ivo: That's irrelevant though for `typeof` checks, since your benchmark is comparing strings against numbers.

Comment: @TimDown And? `===` will never be slower, but `==` will, so general advise is still to use `===`. And don't trust Nick's Benchmark, FX4beta detects that the variables never change and yields 1.797,693,134,862,315,7e+308 on one of the tests...

Comment: @Ivo: My point is that there's no advantage whatsoever in using `===` over `==` in a `typeof` comparison.

Comment: @TimDown And? Why suddenly use `==` when you use `===` everywhere else? People reading your code will either think "Oh I should fix that" or "He must have a **really** good reason to do this here" the latter case is *very* seldom, I only had one case n the last here where using `==` was actually necessary, and I added a comment there to explain why it needs to be that way.

Comment: @Ivo: You're assuming a default position of always using `===`, which I suspect you've got from Douglas Crockford. This recommendation of his has merit for beginners who may not be fully conversant with how types work in JavaScript, but not everyone works that way. You could equally well assume a default position of always using `==` unless `===` is strictly necessary.

Comment: @all == operator only falls into coersion when left and right hand operandi are of different type. aka. STRING == STRING doesn't use coersion. === is faster, but insignificantly when comparing 2 variables of the same type. Using == on same type might be faster overal when you include script loading and program evaluation to the mix (1 less char).

Comment: @BGerrissen: There's no reason for `===` to be faster than `==` on two operands of the same type. As I pointed out earlier, they are specified to perform exactly the same steps in that case.

Comment: @Ivo: It looks like you're actually right: when using [this testcase](http://jsbin.com/alica4/edit) on my system with FF 3.6.X, `===` tend to be a bit slower than `==`; however, using FF 4.0b7 and Chromium 7.0.517.44 I can't reproduce these results anymore and `===` seems to be significantly faster than `==`.

Comment: These benchmarks are pointless and prove nothing. Firstly, any difference between the performance of `==` and `===` is never, ever going to be a bottleneck in real code or make any kind of perceptible difference. Secondly, these benchmarks are artificial and could be subject to who-knows-what optimizations in browsers' JavaScript engines that would not be possible in regular situations.

Comment: @Tim: you're right and I agree that these kind of optimizations will not lead to a noticeable improvement. Wasn't it Donald Knuth who advised against premature optimizations?

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly check that it's a function before calling it.

```
if (typeof(functionName) == "function")
    functionName();
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around `functionName`; `typeof` is an operator, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by `loaded`?

In general you should use something like the `onload` event to make sure all your scripts have been loaded before you call them. In case you just want to whether a function has been declared or not you can use the `typeof` operator:

```
// Check the type of "myRandomFunction"
// Note: typeof is the only way you can use undeclared variables without raising an exception
if (typeof myRandomFunction === 'function') {
    myRandomFunction()
}
```